# Rails: How to redirect back to original page after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app which allows the user to browse the site and log in from any page (login link is in the common header). Once a successful login occurs, the user is currently redirected from the login page to root_url.

It would be more friendly to redirect_to the original page. I attempted to store the named route of the originating page into session, but those appear to be objects, so unable to pass. Also, not all routes come with the named helpers. On the other hand, when I pass the literal path as a string to the redirect_to, e.g. 'orders/index', Rails interprets the /action as an id parameter and errors out.

Would would be the Rails way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There are several answers answered for the "Rails way to do this" for this problem, please go through the "Related" link at the bottom right section of this page.  I'm sure you'll find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: People, tag your question as needed with a proper rails version you are using!

Comment: As for the redirect, if it's rails 3.2 or greater `redirect_to :back` will do what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the URL of the page a user is coming from by using `request.referrer` inside your controller.

Comment: Doesn't always work for my situation, but learned something new -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Rails 5 Update) You can use redirect_back to return the user to the page they just came from.

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

This method requires you set a fallback location because the location is pulled from the browser and it's not always guaranteed to be set.

See the rails guides for more on [`redirect_back`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to)